# Open source alternative to Adobe Edge Inspect

Tags: software-recommendation

I finally got around to trying out Adobe Edge Inspect today and was extremely disappointed.

I found an alternative named Ghostlab but am trying to find a free or open-source alternative.

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this software: [Muir](http://labs.iqfoundry.com/)

Its what you search.